# Why I can't call method on nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, air

In my html file which is in Adobe AIR project, I write following code to get a reference to the application descriptor:

```
var appXML = air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
```

The statement is executed successfully. I can see appXML is referenced to the runtime.XML object from debugger. And if I call alert(appXML), I could see the application descriptor content shown in the alert dialog.

But, if I try to call a method on appXML like appXML.namespace(), then error will be thrown said that:

```
TypeError: Value  does not allow function calls.
```

And so as every method I tried, all failed. But the same method call works well in Actionscript.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

To read the application descriptor file with JavaScript, you can use the DOMParser.

```
var AppXmlParser = new DOMParser(); 
var AppXML = AppXmlParser.parseFromString(air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor, "text/xml").getElementsByTagName('application')[0];
var AppName = AppXML.getElementsByTagName("filename")[0].firstChild.data;   
var AppVersion = AppXML.getElementsByTagName("version")[0].firstChild.data;
```